# Two (or more) dimensional dynamically created arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, matrix

I am implementing a dynamic programming algorithm that needs to create some two dimensional memory before it starts (the size of the memory depends on the parameters, also there are no clear upper bounds for these). I tried to use a normal 2-dim C++ array, but obviously I don't know the second dimension up front, so it didn't work. What is the most reasonable way to achieve it? Are there any classes from the standard library or boost that would make it as easy as it should be?

The functionality I need is rather basic: create MxN, get or set matrix[i][j]

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that strikes me off the top of my head would be **the ugly way**: Implement it as a single-dimensioned array, and perform the double indexing manually with something like:

```
value = arr[i*num_i + j];
```

You could always write a class to hide the uglyness...

Comment: Increasing `num_i` will be a bit nasty too, but if that's also encapsulated in the class it's a reasonable solution.

Comment: +1 For at least somebody not advocating a vector/array of vector's. I don't know why people always want that when hearing of 2-dimensional array? It's you who defines the dimension and not the memory layout.

Comment: The suggested approach has been successfully implemented in several C++ matrix libraries, with all the ugliness hidden away from the user. One recent example is the [Armadillo library](http://arma.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 1):

The most basic way you could go is just use an array of std::vectors.  You can then resize the vectors any time you like.

Also, if you can just defer creation of the array until you know both dimensions, you could use boost.MultiArray.  I think that might be more what you're looking for.

Comment: That's what I did for now, but then I need to remember to resize N independent vectors, which is a bit of a code smell.

Comment: Having just written the same answer and deleted it, I agree with Nathan.  Reserving space in each vector is trivial - just use a loop through the array up to the constant size you used to create it.  It's 2 lines of code and it would do every vector - how much more efficient do you expect to make it>?  You can't really use any tricks if you don't know the 2nd-dimension size when you create the array of vectors.  If you want something even simpler, then just dynamically allocate the memory on the heap - but that's no better :)

Comment: I agree with you on the code smell. Probably your best bet is just to wrap it up in a class of your own making (we're talking probably 10 lines of code here).  Most of the libraries out there that deal with matrices, are more linear algebra.  They're probably not going to support dynamically resizing the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple 2d array requires just a few lines of code

```
template<typename T>
struct Matrix2d
{
    int rows, cols;
    std::vector<T> data;
    Matrix2d(int rows, int cols) : rows(rows), cols(cols), data(rows*cols)
    { }

    T operator()(int i, int j) const { return data[i*cols+j]; }
    T& operator()(int i, int j) { return data[i*cols+j]; }
};
```

Element access is done using `mat(i, j)` for reading and `mat(i, j) = v` for writing.

As James Kanze suggested for the special case of a 2d array it's also easy to get the C++ standard array syntax `mat[i][j]` and `mat[i][j] = v` for element access using `operator[]` instead of `operator()`:

```
    T* operator[](int i) { return &data[i*cols]; }
    const T* operator[](int i) const { return &data[i*cols]; }
```

With this solution however it gets harder to extend to an higher number of dimensions (a trivial problem with `mat(i, j, k)` notation).

Comment: This is one solution (and I'm not saying it's wrong).  Another possibility is to define `operator[]( int i ) { return &data[i * cols]; }` (and its `const` equivalent); this supports the classical `m[i][j]` notation (but would require the introduction of proxies to handle bounds checking, or dimensions greater than 2).

Comment: I thought about it, but it gets annoying to extend the same approach to higher dimensions; this code instead can be extended trivially. A more general solution would be IMO to separate the storage from the accessor. This would support shared submatrices and in this case everything becomes more uniform (mat[i] is an (n-1) dimensional matrix) and allows also for other nice things (e.g. working on submatrices and even for example the submatrix of odd columns). with more trickery it would be possible to write `mat[ANY][i]` to mean slicing on second dimension... and so on and so on... :-D

Comment: IMHO, the choice should be based on the desired syntax, not the ease of writing one basic class.  As to the desired syntax, of course, it's really a matter of taste; there is no one right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a using a vector would be a good idea here, assuming you either don't plan on copying it around much, or don't mind the overhead of the copy.   This code is untested, might not be 100% right)

```
typedef std::vector< std::vector< int > > 2dVector;

2dVector vec( 2 );
vec[ 0 ].resize( someSize );
vec[ 1 ].resize( someSize );

vec[ 0 ][ 0 ] = 100;
//Keep on doing stuff here.
```

Alternatively, you could use something like a [boost::shared_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm) (or the tr1/c++11 equivalets) to dynamically allocate your array (this code is also untested, might not be right):

```
typedef boost::shared_array< boost::shared_array< int > > 2dArray;

2dArray arr( new boost::shared_array< int >( firstDimensionSize ) );
BOOST_FOREACH( boost::shared_array< int >& inner, arr )
{
   inner = new int[ secondDimensionSize ];
}

arr[ 0 ][ 1 ] = 100;
```

EDIT: A quick google also reveals the [boost multidimensional array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html#sec_introduction) library.  I've not used it, or read the description much, but perhaps it is worth looking into